# PhpStorm getting post request in the REST Client issue

Tags: php, json, rest, phpstorm

I have an issue with getting post data in PhpStorm.

My REST Client configuration is:

```
HTTP method : POST
HOST/port: http://templates.local
Path: public/index.php/template/nl_nl/html/sales/invoice
Headers:
Accept:application/json
Cache-Control:no-cache
Authorization:Basic YWRtaW46d2VsY29tZQ==
```

and from the Request Body I selected: `File upload(multipart/form-data)` or `File contents` or `Text` I inserted my JSON content or selected the JSON file and when I do a `var_dump($_POST)` in my controller . It's `null`. I suppose no post data were sent.

Can someone give me an idea, why or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1) Always state IDE version -- it's possible that there were some issues in the past that were fixed only in latest version; 2) Right now it could be https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10265 for example 3) Would be good to see a screenshot as well rather that just textual version of your REST settings (possible nuances); 4) I'm not sure about REST Client tool window (only used it for GET requests) ... but have you tried text-based REST Client that is available in 2017.3 version? https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2017/09/editor-based-rest-client/

Comment: My version is 2016.3.3

Comment: Just in case, what web server do you use?